# How to find it the array of size 'x' is completely filled or not, in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, g++

```
int size = 10;
int arr[size] = {};
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    arr[i] = i;
```

Now how do I find if the array is filled or not in the code.
I know `arr[size - 1] = 9`, but what is `arr[size]` and beyond?
How do i compare `arr[size] == ?` using `if` statement, or is there another way? I am using ubnutu and this is the compiler `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0`.

Comment: `arr[size]` and beyond is anything, and undefined behaviour to use. What values would you have in your array? You could for instance fill it with `-1` or `0` and then check if the value is not that. Otherwise, you could use `std::optional`, then have `std::optional<int> arr[3] = { 1,  std::nullopt, 3 };` and then you will be able to write `if (arr[1])` etc.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "partially filled in" array in C++. All arrays have their declared size, when instantiated. Whether or not the values in the array are initialized, or uninitialized, is a different issue. That's something that C++ will not tell you. It's your responsibility to keep track of, and initialize all objects before they are used. C++ will not do this for you.

Comment: A VLA (Variable length array), as used by you in the above code, is not allowed in C++. So, please do not use it at all. And basically, try to avoid C-Style arrays in C++ in general. There is no need for a C-Style array in C++.

Answer (score 1):

When you use raw arrays, it is your responsibility to handle that memory and keep track of what has been written.
This sounds like a good usecase for a `std:vector` instead. Especially by making use of its `reserve(size)` function.
With reserve you tell how much memory to keep for your data and then you can fill that array with `push_back(content)`, retrieving the current number of filled elements with `size()` (of course reserve is just an optimization to avoid re-allocating the memory because even without it, a vector will dynamically grow).

Answer (score 1):

> Now how do I find if the array is filled or not

All arrays are always "filled". An array of `N` elements contains `N` elements and no less.

An element of trivial type could have an indeterminate value. There is no way to find whether a value is indeterminate. The behaviour of reading an indeterminate value is undefined.

In your example, you value initialised the array, so it is filled with value initialised elements (before the loop where you change the values). Which in case of `int` means that the array is filled with zeroes. You can test whether an element is zero or not like this:

```
if (arr[i])
    // not zero
else
    // is zero
```

---

> but what is arr[size] and beyond?

There is no "`arr[size]` and beyond" because those indices are outside the bounds of the array. The behaviour of accessing values outside the bounds of an array is undefined.